# when i insert data in two tables in mysql the second table check that if pCode is already exist or not

Tags: jquery, mysql, jsp

I have an html page that can be store ItemCode,ItemName,Quantity,Price. I have two tables in mysql (1)purchase(2)stock. i want to store data in both tables but in stock table i don't want to store duplicate value i want when in stock table have same pCode that is already exist in stock table then it can be update only quantity of that product. it works for only in one row when i entered more than one row which is already exist in stock table. it can only update tha quantity of last row.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="newjsp.jsp" method="post">

       <table width="500" border="1" id="POITable">
    <tr>
        <td>No.</td>
        <td>Item Code</td>
        <td>Item Name</td>
        <td>quantity</td>
        <td>price</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="itemcode_1" id="itemcode_1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="itemname_1" id="itemname_1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="quantity_1" id="quantity_1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputs lst" name="price_1"  id="price_1" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
        <span id="counter"></span>
        </tr>
</table>
                <input type="submit" value="submit"/>        
        </form>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>

var i = $('table tr').length;
var count=0;
$(document).on('keyup', '.lst', function(e) 
{
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) {

     count = $('table tr').length;
    $('#counter').html(count);


    html = '<tr id="POITable>';
    html += '<form action="newjsp.jsp" method="post">';
    html += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="itemcode_' + i + '" id="itemcode_' + i + '" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="itemname_' + i + '" id="itemname_' + i + '" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="quantity_' + i + '" id="quantity_' + i + '" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs lst" name="price_' + i + '" id="price_' + i + '" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>';
    html += '<input type="hidden"  name="count" value="'+ count +'"/>';
    html += '<input type="submit" value="submit"/>';
    html += '</form>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table').append(html);
    $(this).focus().select();
    i++;
  }

});

$(document).on('keydown', '.inputs', function(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) {
    var index = $('.inputs').index(this) + 1;
    $('.inputs').eq(index).focus();

  }
});

$(document).keypress(
    function(event){
     if (event.which == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
      }


});

   function deleteRow(row)
   {

    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;

    document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);

   }
    </script>
```

**Insert JSP File**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page language="java"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/bootstrap.css"/>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <%

        try
        {
            String Itemcode=null;
           String Itemname=null; 
           String quantity=null; 
           String price=null; 
           int cc=1;
           String qty=null;

           String count[]=request.getParameterValues("count");
           for(String c:count)
           {
           cc=Integer.valueOf(c);

           }

           out.println(cc+"<br>");

          String query = "INSERT INTO jquery ";
          String query1="INSERT INTO stock";
          for (int i = 1; i<=cc; i++)
          {
           Itemcode=request.getParameter("itemcode_" + i);           
           Itemname=request.getParameter("itemname_" + i);
           quantity=request.getParameter("quantity_" + i);  
           price=request.getParameter("price_" + i);  
          if(Itemname!=null && quantity!=null && price!=null)
              {
           query += ((i == 1) ? "values" : ",") + "('"+Itemcode+"','"+Itemname+"','"+quantity+"','"+price+"')";

           query1 += ((i == 1) ? "values" : ",") + "('"+Itemcode+"','"+Itemname+"','"+quantity+"','"+price+"')";
              }
              else
              {

              }
          }
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atm","root","root");
          Statement st=con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs;

          int o=st.executeUpdate(query);
          out.println("Success"+"<br>");


         rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM stock");
         while(rs.next())
         {
           qty=rs.getString("quantity");


         }
          if(qty!=null)
          {
          int q=st.executeUpdate("update stock set  quantity=quantity+'"+quantity+"', amount='"+price+"' where item_code='"+Itemcode+"'");
         }

          else
          {
        int p=st.executeUpdate(query1);

         }

          }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          System.out.println(e);  
        }

        %>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your update query is out of while loop of stock that's why it it updating only last row.

Comment: i already did this but it cannot work in while loop also...

Comment: How can we insert data through comma seperate...for e.g. i have 3 columns  item_code,item_name,quantity when i insert multiples rows data through html table then it will store in mysql like...101,102,phone,game,3,5